# Flutter error when adding "cloud_firestore"

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I get this error when i add "cloud_firestore:" to pubspec.yaml :

```
$ flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on Infinix X627 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                              1.6s
Resolving dependencies...                                           5.4s
Note: /home/muhammad/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.11/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    
Note: /home/muhammad/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.11/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.                      
D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 80689 > 65536)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                

* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/0.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/1.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/4.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/5.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/6.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/7.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/8.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/9.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/10.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/11.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/12.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/13.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/14.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/15.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/16.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/17.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/18.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/19.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/20.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/21.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/22.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/23.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/24.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/25.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/26.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/27.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/28.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/29.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/30.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/31.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/32.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/33.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/34.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/35.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/36.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/37.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/38.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/39.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/40.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/41.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/42.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/43.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/44.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/45.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/46.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/47.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/48.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/49.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/50.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/51.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/52.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/53.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/54.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/55.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/56.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/57.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/58.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/59.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/60.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/62.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/63.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/64.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/65.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/66.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/67.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/68.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/69.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/72.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/73.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/74.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/75.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/76.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/77.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/78.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/79.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/80.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/81.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/82.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/83.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/84.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/85.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/86.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/87.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/88.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/89.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/90.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/91.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/92.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/93.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/94.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/95.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/96.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/97.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/98.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/99.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/100.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/101.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/102.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/103.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/104.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/105.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/107.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/108.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/109.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/110.jar, /home/muhammad/Documents/lab/flutter/teststore/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/111.jar
  The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.     
  Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              

BUILD FAILED in 1m 36s                                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        96.8s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

(I'm new to flutter and android development)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `cloud_firestore` is a decently sized dependency, you need to enable `multidex`.
View [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle) to configure your app to support `multidex`.

If you don't want to do that, all you have to do is set your `minSdkVersion` to 21 or higher in your `build.gradle`. However, that does make it so that your app doesn't support devices below 5.1.

Depending on how many users you want to support, I'd recommend just upgrading your `minSdkVersion` since it's the easiest way. It's up to you however.